# MySQL server access denied while connecting

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

I have installed Mysql on Mac os 10.7 using dmg installer, it got installed at location `/usr/local/mysql` I also installed MySQL.prefpane, where I can start and stop the server using services. 
i am facing below problems.

```
mysql> create database test    ;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'ets'
```

same happens when I am trying to invoke mysql by using below command

```
./mysql -u root root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Even when I created a connection using Eclipse to mysql db then also I got similar kind of exception.

Just want to know after installation do I need to make any further configuration related to user management and access privileges?

Comment: Thanks @Nelson, but still m facing access denied exception while connecting through Java Program getting exception related to `roo@localhost` access denied. But thanks `create schema <name>` did work.

Comment: Ok great! Please mark that as the correct answer then. But it seems strange that you cannot connect. It could have to do with a socket setting maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

./mysql -uroot -pPassword

To give the user all priviliges, execute this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'yourpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Also try

```
CREATE SCHEMA test;
```

Comment: I think the standard root password in MySQL in actualy password all in small letters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It got logged in but still i am not able to create schema/database `mysql> create database TEST_DB` as showing error `ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database 'TEST_DB' (errno: 2)`

Comment: Try CREATE SCHEMA 'test_db'

Comment: also, can you execute 'show grants' on command line to see that you have the proper priviliges, allthough the root user  should have it